# Avoid matrix half-vectorization in LAPACK

Tags: c++, c, optimization, matrix, lapack

The answer to my question is most likely "No", but maybe someone has a smart solution to this problem?

Here's the problem. For example, the lapack function [`zheev`](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/zheev_ex.c.htm) calculates the eigenvalues of a complex Hermitian matrix. The problem is that all C++ implementations of matrices store either row-major or column-major matrices, while `zheev()` takes a dense upper or lower triangular matrix.

So my question is: Is there any way to avoid copying my matrix to a new array that stores only the lower or upper triangular part and use my current full matrix in lapack?

Comment: Do you have an indication that this is a problem? The running time of zheev, or anything interesting in LAPACK, probably dominates the time to needed for transformation.

Comment: @AmiTavory You're probably right, but still, it's annoying to have to vectorize and devectorize my matrix just because of this weird interface lapack has. Also the memory cost is not negligible. I deal with matrices of side-length of about 2^16. So I would like to avoid wasting memory.

Comment: In the example you linked, `zheev()` makes use of a LDA.N=N.N matrix. Indeed, the matrix does not need to be packed: you may not have to make a copy of your matrix. Watch out:  `zheev()` modifies `A`! You may be interested by [`zhpev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/d62/zhpev_8f_source.html) (dedicated to packed storage) or you might be interested by [`zhbev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/d77/zhbev_8f_source.html) (dedicated to band storage, if it's ideal for your matrix).

Comment: @francis Thank you very much! Actually I noticed that in the example but wasn't able to explain it. Can we say that every function has a copy that takes non-dense elements?

Comment: You're welcome! Every function of LAPACK refers to a particular matrix storage. See [the naming convention](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node24.html) of LAPACK. In `ZHEEV`, `Z` refers to double precision complex, `HE` refers to an Hermitian matrix of size N.N in memory. Depending on the argument `UPLO`, the upper triangular part is used or ignored. Anyway, the matrix can be populated as if it were a general unpacked matrix of size `N.N`. In this case, the value of the argument UPLO should not change the obtained eigenvalues. Finally, `EV` refers to computation of eigenvalue.

Comment: @francis One last question, the functions you provided give "left or right eigenvectors" as described in the links you provided. Does that make any difference? Because `zheev` doesn't mention left/right eigenvectors at all.

Comment: See [this page about left/right eigenvectors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvector.html) ""if A is a self-adjoint matrix (i.e., it is Hermitian), then the left and right eigenvectors are adjoint matrices"". So it is very easy to compute one from the other. I assume that `zheev()` returns right eigenvectors... Anyway, given the differences of conventions between C/fortran, row/col major, it's a good idea to perform a simple matrix-vector product to check whether eigenvectors are considered and avoid any mistake.

Comment: @francis Actually I tried to read a little about right and left eigenvectors, but didn't learn much. So I'll have to thoroughly read about them. I'm afraid I'll have to do a complicated operation to get the other kind, which could be expensive (it's an inverse, apparently).

Comment: Don't be afraid! Say the right eigenvector is the column `(  0.34+J0.00, 42.0+J10.2, 13.3-J12.5 )`. Then, the corresponding left eigenvector is the line `(  0.34+J0.00, 42.0-J10.2, 13.3+J12.5 )` . Corresponding terms are complex conjugate. That's all that is to be done!

Comment: @francis Thanks. Feel free to add this information to an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you linked on [`zheev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/dee/zheev_8f.html) **already makes use of an unpacked `LDA*N=N*N` matrix**. Indeed, the hermitian matrix does not need to be packed: you may not have to make a copy of your matrix. Watch out: **`zheev()` modifies the matrix  `A`!**

LAPACK handles other storage mode for matrices: **see [the naming scheme](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node24.html) of LAPACK**. For instance:

- [`zheev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/dee/zheev_8f.html): the memory footprint `N*N` and the storage are similar to the one of general unpacked `N*N` matrices.  Depending on the value of the argument `UPLO`, the upper triangular part is used or ignored. Anyway, the matrix can be populated as if it were a general unpacked matrix of size `N*N`. In this case, the value of the argument `UPLO` should not change the obtained eigenvalues.
- [`zhpev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/d62/zhpev_8f.html): packed format. Either the upper diagonal items or the lower diagonal items are stored, depending on the value of the argument `UPLO`. The memory footprint for matrix storage is `(N*(N+1))/2`.
- [`zhbev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/d77/zhbev_8f.html): dedicated to band storage.

As you work with C or C++, here is a sample code using `zheev()` via the interface LAPACKE. It can be compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lm -Wall`. Moreover, this code ensures that **the function `zheev()` returns the right eigenvectors**, not the left ones. The left eigenvectors are the the complex conjugates of the right ones, as explained [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvector.html).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <lapacke.h>


int main(void){

    int n=200;

    srand(time(NULL));

    // allocate the matrix, unpacked storage
    double complex** A=malloc(n*sizeof(double complex*));
    if(A==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    A[0]=malloc(n*n*sizeof(double complex));
    if(A[0]==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        A[i]=&A[0][n*i];
    }

    //populte the matrix, only the lower diagonal part
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
            A[i][j]=rand()/((double)RAND_MAX)+rand()/((double)RAND_MAX)*I;

        }
        A[i][i]=rand()/((double)RAND_MAX)+42.;
    }



    //saving the matrix, because zheev() changes it.
    double complex** As=malloc(n*sizeof(double complex*));
    if(As==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    As[0]=malloc(n*n*sizeof(double complex));
    if(As[0]==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        As[i]=&As[0][n*i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
            As[i][j]=A[i][j];
        }
        As[i][i]=A[i][i];
    }
    //transpose part, conjugate
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            As[i][j]=conj(A[j][i]);
        }
    }
    /*
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
for(j=0;j<n;j++){
printf("%g+I%g ",creal(As[i][j]),cimag(As[i][j]));
}
printf("\n");
}
     */

    //let's get the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors!
    double* w=malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    if(w==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    int lda = n;
    int info = LAPACKE_zheev(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'V', 'L', n, A[0], lda,  w);
    if(info<0){
        fprintf(stderr,"argument %d has illegal value\n",-info);
    }
    if(info>0){
        fprintf(stderr,"algorithm failed to converge... bad condition number ?\n");
    }

    //printing the eigenvalues...
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d %g\n",i,w[i]);
    }

    //let's check that the column i of A is now a right eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i]...
    int l=42;

    double complex *res=malloc(n*sizeof(double complex));
    if(res==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        res[i]=0;
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            res[i]+=As[i][j]*A[j][l];
        }
        res[i]-=w[l]*A[i][l];
    }
    double norm2res=0;
    double norm2vec=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        norm2res+=creal(res[i])*creal(res[i])+cimag(res[i])*cimag(res[i]);
        norm2vec+=creal(A[i][l])*creal(A[i][l])+cimag(A[i][l])*cimag(A[i][l]);
    }
    printf("the norm of the eigenvector is %g\n",sqrt(norm2vec));
    printf("||Ax-\\lambda*x||_2/||x||_2 is about %g\n",sqrt(norm2res/norm2vec));
    //free the matrix
    free(A[0]);
    free(A);

    free(As[0]);
    free(As);

    free(w);
    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, a copy of the matrix is performed, but that is not required by `LAPACKE_zheev()`. Dealing with a matrix of 2000*2000, the memory footprint of the code above is about 167MB. That's more than twice of the size of the matrix (64MB) because a copy is performed. But it would be less than twice if the copy were not performed. Hence, `LAPACKE_zheev()` does not perform any copy of the matrix. Notice also that [`LAPACKE_zheev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/dea/lapacke__zheev_8c_source.html) allocates some space for the working array.